# Different options to organize Web API controllers with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Assume, I have the following entity set below.

**Phone**(PhoneId, PhoneNumber)

**Person**(PersonId, FirstName, LastName)

**Company**(CompanyId, CompanyName)

**Broker**(BrokerId, BrokerName)

**PersonPhone**(PhoneId, PersonId, PhoneType)

**CompanyPhone**(PhoneId, CompanyId, PhoneType)

**BrokerPhone**(PhoneId, BrokerId)

As entity name suggests,

1. Phone/Broker/Company maintains their domain data.
2. PersonPhone/CompanyPhone/BrokerPhone tables keeps a mapping of different entities and there phone numbers.

The system needs to allow a user to create/update the aforementioned entities as well as add/remove phone numbers for them.

Question:
What should the structure of Web API for this kind of scenario be.

My confusion is which controller should handle the call **"add a phone to person"**.

Should it be directed to PersonController because there may be some specific business logic when adding phone to Person and a path like **/api/person/{{personid}}/addphone** makes sense from client's perspective.

Or the call should be directed to PhoneController.AddPhoneToPerson method in which case the path might be **/api/phone/attachtoperson/{{phoneid}}**

Which one makes more sense?

Comment: Step back and ask yourself why you've got these entity-attached controllers anyway. IMO controllers should be geared toward use cases, not entities. It's great that you already focus on a use case: "add a phone to person". Probably this is part of some greater task area in your app. Organize your controllers toward these task areas.

Comment: The reason I have Entity focused controllers is because in visual studio you can generate WEB API from entities; so to reduce effort I stared with that.  However, that may only be suitable for simple applications where entities might relatively disconnected.

Comment: I think you nailed it there. The tooling is great to get you going, but one day you have to grow up :). That said, similar dilemmas may pop up anywhere. From an OO point of view the `Person` would be the most suitable entry point because `Person` owns the phone, so `Person` (in a broader sense) would encapsulate phone possession. The phone itself is just an oblivious asset.